# How to source (or run) tail output

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to load serveral variables from a file (not `.bash_*`) which has similar to:

```
export MY_VAR='foo'
```

The command I was using to "source" this was

```
`tail -1 myFile`
```

This works, but it I `echo $MY_VAR`, I get

```
'foo'
```

But it I actually run `export MY_VAR='foo'` in the terminal, then `echo $MY_VAR` it outputs:

```
foo
```

Why the descrepancy in the quotes and how do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `source myFile` command to "source" the file?

Comment: It is the apache envvars file, I add a few envvars for my site, and need only those to be sourced when I log in over ssh. I am totally open to other strategies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using backticks is something that is referred to as command substitution.  The shell substitutes it after parsing tokens in the output.  Since it encountered quotes in the output, it'd escape those.  As such, it'd execute:

```
export MY_VAR=\'foo\'
```

leaving the variable surrounded with quotes.

You could instead make use of process substitution and continue to use the `source` command:

```
source <(tail -1 myFile)
```